# django celery - how to send request.FILES['photo'] to task

Tags: django, celery

i'm trying to send request.FILES['photo'], an uploaded file from my site, to tCelery via:

```
tasks.upload_photos.delay(img=request.FILES['photo'])
```

I get a pickle error because it cannot serialize it.  What is the way to send a file to task?

error: "can't pickle StringO objects"
thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read the file contents into a string, then pack it with the content type in a dict and send that.

Comment: What if it is a very big file and you do not have enough memory?

Comment: Please give an example @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams

Comment: Any example for this?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams any example on this :D

Comment: This is completely IMO off the point. We wanna use Celery to lessen the burden of file upload and you suggest to read the whole file in memory. This is not appropriate way to deal with this issue IMHO

Answer (score 3):

If you plan on saving the file, you can save the file to a model, then pass the id/pk to a celery task.

Comment: What do you mean by defining a model? Are you implying to save file in some kind of database - AFAIK mongodb does just that - and then pass the id to task? Can you make your answer more vivid.